# Robust Difference-in-Differences: What is the propensity score doing?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, propensity-scores, robust

[Callaway and Sant'Anna (2022)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407620303948?via%3Dihub) describe a doubly robust difference-in-differences (DiD) method that is attractive in staggered DiD (multi-group treatment times) for several reasons. It can prevent "bad comparisons" between not-yet-treated and treated to which a classic TWFE DiD approach is agnostic. It allows recovery of various ATT aggregations.

It also uses propensity scores (PS), but I'm having trouble understanding how and why they are used. Can someone explain why this is done? How is the PS used in reported pre-treatment parallel trends and post-treatment coefficients?

Extreme example to help with intuition: let's say we have only one treatment group and the never-treated and not-yet-treated are extremely similar in pre-treatment outcome trends and pre-treatment trends in covariates (X) but positive ATT and differing X in post. Wouldn't we get meaningless propensity scores for treatment propensity? How would this information be used in the model?

From page 203:

> Next, denote the generalized propensity score as $p_{g,s}(X)= P(G_g = 
>  1|X, G_g + (1 − D_s)(1 − G_g) = 1)$. Note that $p_{g,s}(X)$ indicates
> the probability of being first treated at time g, conditional on
> pre-treatment covariates X and on either being a member of group g (in
> this case, $G_g = 1$) or a member of the “not-yet-treated” group by time
> s (in this case, $(1−D_s)(1−G_g ) = 1)$.

$D_s$ is treatment status at time s.